# Using extractValue to get value from element in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have following xml

```
<EmployeeList>
  <Employee>
    <EmpID>11</EmpID>
    <EmpName>ABC</EmpName>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmpID>12</EmpID>
    <EmpName>XYZ</EmpName>
  </Employee>
</EmployeeList>
```

I want to insert element value based on the count of Employee in to to Employee table

I have employee table which has id and name as columns .

I got below code snippet

```
declare xml_content text;
declare v_row_index int unsigned default 0;   
declare v_row_count int unsigned;  
declare v_xpath_row varchar(255); 

set xml_content = load_file(path);

-- calculate the number of row elements.   
set v_row_count  = extractValue(xml_content, concat('count(', node, ')')); 

-- loop through all the row elements    
while v_row_index < v_row_count do                
    set v_row_index = v_row_index + 1;        
    set v_xpath_row = concat(node, '[', v_row_index, ']/@*');
    insert into applicants values (
        extractValue(xml_content, concat(v_xpath_row, '[1]')),
        extractValue(xml_content, concat(v_xpath_row, '[2]'))
    );
end while;
```

The above works only for attribute values.

What I have done so far is :

```
-- loop through all the row elements    
    while v_row_index < v_row_count do                
        set v_row_index = v_row_index + 1;        
        set v_xpath_row = concat(node, '[', v_row_index, ']/@*');
set @I=1,@j=2;
        insert into applicants values (
            extractValue(xml_content, '//Employee[$@i]'),
            extractValue(xml_content, '//Employee[$@j]')
        );
    end while;
```

**What I am trying to do :**

I have an xml as above mentioned.
There are two records of Employee in it.
Want to insert those in Employee table

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Have you considered [`LOAD XML`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-xml.html)?

Comment: MySQL version 5.5. And whereas LOAD XML cant be used inside an Store Procedure

Comment: But as its a migration of sql store procedure in to MySQL , I have to carry out changes in store procedure only.

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow to use "LOAD XML INLINE Statement" inside a store procedure.. .

Comment: Apologies.  That I did not know.  Having tried it myself, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a procedure as shown to read from an XML and insert into the table:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `import_applicant_xml`()
BEGIN
    declare path varchar(255);
    declare node varchar(255);
    declare xml_content text;
    declare v_row_index int unsigned default 0;   
    declare v_row_count int unsigned;  
    declare v_empID varchar(255); 
    declare v_empName varchar(255); 
    set path = 'C:\\demo\\employee.xml';
    set node = 'Employee';
    set xml_content = load_file(path);

    -- calculate the number of row elements.   
    set v_row_count  = extractValue(xml_content, concat('count(//', node, ')')); 
    -- loop through all the row elements    
    while v_row_index < v_row_count do                
        set v_row_index = v_row_index + 1;        
        set v_empID = concat('//',node, '[', v_row_index, ']/EmpID');
        set v_empName = concat('//',node, '[', v_row_index, ']/EmpName');
        insert into employee values (
            extractValue(xml_content,v_empID),
            extractValue(xml_content, v_empName)
        );
    end while;
END
```

You can pass the path and the node values as `IN PARAMETERS` to the procedure and make it a bit more dynamic.

Comment: I have taken your XML as a sample to test the code, you might have to change the XPath declarations to suit your requirement.

Comment: can I do some generic in node terms over here. As in my situation I am already passing xml element as an text , there is no additional param for passing nodes. So is there any function where I can say parent node and it gives me all its children nodes value . For eg what I was trying to do  : extractValue(xml_content, '//Employee[$@i]'),

Comment: @Malcolm I'm not sure if one can get the list of child nodes, you can get the count of the child nodes of employee like this :  
`set v_child_count  = extractValue(xml_content, concat('count(//', node, '[1]/*)')); `   
and later you can access the children like :  
`set v_empID = concat('//',node, '[', v_row_index, ']/*[1]');  
set v_empName = concat('//',node, '[', v_row_index, ']/*[2]');`

Comment: You can replace [1] and [2] from the above comment with your variable.